# Double Scramble 2: End of Year Scramble?

Tags: wordplay, lateral-thinking

Following on from the Scary Sequence is another overly done scrambling. We have a sequence that is doubly scrambled (both the order and the terms themselves).  Can you reverse out the sequence and re-order?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct order should be

> Caretaker
>  Feverish
>  Comics Publisher
>  Orange Fruit
>  Pyramid People
>  Gin Berry
>  Young Capulet
>  Increase

Because

> Each of these phrases represents another word which begins with the same three letters as a month of the year. In order, we have
>  Caretaker - **JAN**itor
>  Feverish  - **FEB**rile
>  Comics Publisher - **MAR**vel
>  Orange Fruit  - **APR**icot
>  Pyramid People - **MAY**an
>  Gin Berry - **JUN**iper
>  Young Capulet - **JUL**iet
>  Increase - **AUG**ment
>  and we put them in order of occurrence of the months during the year.